# In Forbidden Island, can a Navigator move an Explorer diagonally?

Tags: forbidden-island

My wife and I played a game of Forbidden Island last night.  She got the Navigator adventurer, and I was the Explorer.

The Navigator's special ability is that it can move any other player up to 2 adjacent tiles.  "Adjacent" usually means up/down/left/right, however the Explorer's special ability is that it can move diagonally too, so: Can the navigator move the explorer to adjacent *diagonal* tiles, or just the standard up/down/left/right?

(I hope the answer is 'yes', as we *just* managed to win assuming 'yes' to the above with just 2 tiles left when we got off Fools Landing!)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Good question!  And fortunately for you, the answer is "yes", as per [these clarifications](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/article/5017773#5017773)
by Matt Leacock, the designer of the game:

> The Navigator can move the Diver up to 2 adjacent tiles. The first
>   tile may be missing. The second tile may not be missing because the
>   Diver must end her turn on a tile.
>
> When the Navigator moves the Explorer to adjacent spaces, he may move
>   him diagonally.
>
> The Navigator moves the Pilot to adjacent spaces like any other
>   adventurer. (The Pilot can't take advantage of his special ability
>   when the Navigator moves him.)